# Is it possible to map a route directly to a view without a controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been gradually moving more code to the client, to the point where many of my controller actions are just:

```
<Route("controller/action/id")>
Overridable Function ActionName() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

and then the view uses javascript and WebApi to hydrate itself with data.

It's a bit annoying to define lots of these identical methods, differing only by name and route.

I'd like, instead, to make a big table of controllers, actions, and routes, and have a single handler or controller that gets all requests matching some pattern and returns the needed view directly.

I can think of various ways to do the routing, but I don't know how to return a view if all I have is an `HttpContext` or `HttpContextBase`, as in an `IHttpHandler` or `RouteBase` derived class.

Comment: [ASP.NET Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started), and its modern successor [ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) are both basically "MVC without the controller". I haven't worked with them much, but my understanding is you get a free out of the box basic route (ex: mysite.com/SomeFolder/Somepage.cshtml) but that you're free to configure additional routes if needed.

Comment: I guess lots of people had similar needs then. But I need to make this work in a framework (that is, non-core) app. Is that possible?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Pages was built on the old ASP.NET framework. So that should be possible. Though documentation will probably be harder to find on it. You really should look at moving to ASP.NET Core as quickly as possible so you stay on a well supported framework.

Comment: I am acutely aware of that need. It's a challenge because of the size of the project.